# simple SQL query returns nothing

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using sqlsrv driver, and I'm trying to make a query like this:

```
$query  = "select * from products";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
echo $result;
```

This returns me nothing. What is wrong with the query or PHP code?

Comment: Does products exist? Is the connection pointing to the right database?

Comment: Yes, products exist, and the conn is conected to the database with that table.

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again? :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to fetch the rows returned. Here is an example I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296196%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: I restarted the service and xampp and we are on the same. I will read that link...

Comment: What does `sqlsrv_errors()` show?  What happens if you try "select count(1) from products" ?

Comment: Bruno is right. Are you actually fetching and echoing rows?

Answer (score 2):

This is how it would be done with a mysql connection. I haven't used sqlsrv driver, so it may not work as is but you get an idea.

Bruno posted a link with sqlsrv driver detailed code.

The real issue is that **you can't just echo $result**. It's an array and you have to do it row by row or write a function that echoes the complete $result. That way you can also filter rows or columns and format every field as you like.

```
$query  = "select id, title, price from products";
$result = mysql_query($conn,$query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num)
{
    $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $title=mysql_result($result,$i,"title");
    $price=mysql_result($result,$i,"price");

    echo "<b>id: $id</b> Product: $title , Price: $price<br>";

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with that the real problem is that you can't echo a result - you have to iterate through the results. Just so you have an example with the sqlsrv extension, here's how I'd do it:

```
$query = "select id, title, price from products";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   echo "<b>id: $row['id']</b> Product: $row['product'], Price: $row['price'];
}
```

-Brian